# Ensure local write with async Infinispan 6.x

Tags: java, redhat, distributed, infinispan, nosql

We're planning to use Infinispan 6.x in master/slave mode with all writes and reads directed to one node; other nodes only serving as backup using asynchronous replication.

In ASYNC replication mode, Infinispan's local writes seem to be asynchronous as well, i.e. a `put(x)` immediately followed by `get(x)` on the same node, causes `get()` to return `null`. (see [this discussion](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/516913).)

We have a use case in which a client forces a `put(x)` and then, in a subsequent request, a `get(x)`. How can we ensure that by the time the second request arrives, the entry is in **local** data container (local map)? SYNC mode is out of the question for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You use the term **local** cache somewhat incorrectly - **local** is one of the modes which does not cause any replication to other nodes. You want to make sure the entry is in *data container* (that's the 'local' map where Infinispan holds the entries).

Anyway, you can't do that if the node which does put() is different from the *primary owner* node for this key. There ways how to achieve that such as [KeyAffinityService](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#KeyAffinityService) but these are not completely bullet proof - between generating the key and using it, there's a slight chance for topology change, so you can't rely on that.

Even in SYNC node you can call putAsync() which delegates the write to another thread and returns a future.

Comment: Thanks, I reworded the question to avoid terminology confusion.
I am using replication (not distribution) - in such case, is there still a notion of primary owner?

Comment: Yes, one node is always primary for each entry. This single point is required to have single lock - in non-transactional mode, the write is sent to primary owner, primary owner locks the entry and sends the update to all backups and after getting ack, unlocks the entry and sends ack to originator.

Comment: If you find other information (for non-transactional mode, with transaction it's a bit different), it's outdated documentation from Infinispan < 5.2 (if I remember correctly in which version it was changed) - in that case please file a bug for the documentation.